# Can help me to make multiple delete in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, delete-row, multiple-choice

I want to be able to delete the data by selecting from this checkbox. Can you help me make it in the codeodeigniter? Please give a few examples of program code fragment. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// get the checkboxes values
$ids = $_POST['ids']; // if the checkboxes are array - ids[]
$this->db->where_in('id', $ids);
$this->db->delete('users');
```